# Подскажите как реализовать данный блок страницы

Tags: html, css

```css
.about_content{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.content img{
 display: block;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100px;
 height: 100px;
 justify-content: center;
}
.content p{
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_us">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
   <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.</p> 
   <div class="about_content">
    <div class="content">
     <img src="img/image1.png" alt="">
     <h3>Treehouse Template</h3>
     <p>Web Design</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <p><img src="img/image1.png" alt="">
     Web Design</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <img src="img/image1.png" alt="">
     <h3>Treehouse Template</h3>
     <p>Web Design</p>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Не обязательно все расписывать, просто подскажите при помощи чего можно реализовать данный блок сайта, и что нужно почитать и выучить для этого. Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: голого html+css хватит

Comment: не пойму как выровнять текст слева и справа

Comment: вы добавьте свой вариант верстки в виде примера кода в вопрос, там спец кнопочка есть, добавить пример кода

Comment: Добавил, но за этот код мне стыдно. А в голову ничего толкового как это реализовать не лезет, возможно из-за отсутствия знаний в этом вопросе

Comment: не надо стыдиться спросить

Comment: ну как, что подскажите

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90891/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если по-простому, например так. В принципе даже flex особо не нужны.

```css
div,
p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.about_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
}

.about_content .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.content img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.about_content .content:nth-child(odd) img {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%)
}

.about_content .content:nth-child(odd) h3,
.about_content .content:nth-child(odd) p {
    padding-right: 70px;
    text-align: right;
}

.about_content .content:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.about_content .content:nth-child(even) img {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.about_content .content:nth-child(even) h3,
.about_content .content:nth-child(even) p {
    padding-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_us">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
        <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.</p>
        <div class="about_content">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt="">
                <h3>Treehouse Template</h3>
                <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
                    of human happiness. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt="">
                <h3>Treehouse Template</h3>
                <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
                    of human happiness. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/an" alt="">
                <h3>Treehouse Template</h3>
                <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
                    of human happiness. </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую