# как сделать картинку по центру, а текст возле картинки - слева или справа, и чтобы условная 3-я часть страницы была пустая

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать текст и картинку как на фото примере?

Comment: откуда этот блок? курсы что ли какие-то? уже было такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955180/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/955211#955211

Comment: да, мастерклас на ютубе смотрел. спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/955297/262779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте применим гибкие контейнеры.

Мы зададим для всей линии свойство `display: flex` и таким образом получим Flex-контейнер с двумя элементами. На пустом месте разместим третий, создав его через псевдо-элемент `::after`. Для левой и правой областей линии зададим `flex-grow: 1`, чтобы они поровну заняли максимально возможное пространство — за счёт этого картинка выровняется по центру. Для текста описания пришлось указать `flex-basis: 0`, а то иначе длинный текст выстраивается в одну строчку, сжимая остальные компоненты линии.

Стили для класса `.line__master-icon` несут чисто оформительскую функцию и на основной каркас не влияют. Вам же, скорее всего, придётся подвести оформление в соответствии с вашей задачей.

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
}
.line_to-left::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.line .line__description {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.line .line__master-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line line_to-left">
  <div class="line__description">
    Довольно длинный произвольный текст с полным описанием блока.
  </div>
  <div class="line__master-icon">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы, конечно, извините, но при чем тут флексы?)

Comment: @DaemonHK, не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: Почему выбор пал именно на них? Потому что "модно, стильно, молодежно"? Какие у них преимущества конкретно ЗДЕСЬ?

Comment: Первое и главное преимущество - простота. По существу требуется указать всего два свойства `display: flex` для контейнера и `flex: 1 0` для боковушек.